# How to create Glue table with Parquet format?

Tags: parquet, aws-glue, aws-cdk

In the documentation I found how to create `Glue table` in `JSON` format but I cannot find how to create one in `Parquet` format.

I think I could provide a subtype of `glue.DataFormat`, but I don't know how to do that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-glue-readme.html

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found what are the working values on Terraform's website. 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/glue_catalog_table.html

```js
    const glue_DataFormat_Parquet = <glue.DataFormat> {
      inputFormat: new glue.InputFormat('org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'),
      outputFormat: new glue.OutputFormat('org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'),
      serializationLibrary: new glue.SerializationLibrary('org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe')
    };
```

Comment: This. Thanks for this anwer, i've been looking for those format for hours with CDK.